# MySQL joining 4 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I'm trying to join 4 tables:

My tables are:

- users (user information),
- groups (group information),
- users_groups (users groups information: many to many. a user can be a member of many groups, a group can have many members),
- user_favorite_group (user's favorite group).

Detailed table info:

users: id, name, email, few other info fields
 e.g. 1, chatu rohra, chaturanga@example.com, few other info fields

groups: id, name, email, few other info fields
 e.g. 1, SOME_GROUP_NAME some@email.com, few other info fields

users_groups: id, user_id, group_id.
 e.g. 1, 1, 1

user_favorite_group: id, user_id, user_group_id.
 e.g. 1, 1, 1

I'm able to join first three tables (users, groups, users_groups) but not the user_favorite_group. My query is:

```
SELECT
users.*,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT groups.name ORDER BY groups.name ASC SEPARATOR ', ') as groups
FROM users_groups
    INNER JOIN users ON users.id = users_groups.user_id
    INNER JOIN groups ON groups.id = users_organizations.organization_id
    WHERE users.id = 1;
```

This gives me:
users.id, users.name, users.email, groups
1, chatu rohra, some@email.com, SOME_GROUP_NAME

What I would like to see is.. assuming there are more groups in the groups table:
1, chatu rohra, some@email.com, "AND_ANOTHER, SOME_GROUP_NAME, SOME_OTHER_GROUP", "SOME_OTHER_GROUP"

The 4th field is a list of groups that I'm a member of and my favorite group as the 5th field.

Any suggestions for name tables, performance would be also great.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a few rows of sample data and the expected results, that way someone else can recreate the issue? An [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) would be helpful if you can make one.

Comment: "`user_favorite_group: id, user_group_id`": does `user_favorite_group` have a `user_id` column? I only see `id`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski You are right. user_id is added to user_favorite_group. Thanks.

Comment: @chatu I thought as much.

Comment: @McAdam331 I am working on adding this question to SQL Fiddle.

Comment: @chatu test out my answer before you go to the effort - I think I understood your need.

Comment: Can a user have more than one favourite group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest path to join your `user_favorite_group` table is to add it as an additional `LEFT JOIN` on the `user_id` to get the *user* part of the relationship, but then add an additional `INNER JOIN` to the `groups` table to get the group's name. It may not work to try to get the group name from the existing `INNER JOIN` against `groups`.

```
SELECT
  users.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT groups.name ORDER BY groups.name ASC SEPARATOR ', ') as groups,
  gfav.name AS favorite_group
FROM users_groups
    INNER JOIN users ON users.id = users_groups.user_id
    INNER JOIN groups ON groups.id = users_organizations.organization_id
    -- Join user to user_favorite_group
    -- Using LEFT JOIN in case the user has no favorite, it will return a NULL.
    LEFT JOIN `user_favorite_group` ON users.id = user_favorite_group.user_id
    -- Join that to `groups` to get its group name
    INNER JOIN groups gfav ON user_favorite_group.user_group_id
WHERE users.id = 1
-- MySQL will allow only users.id in the GROUP BY (or none at all)
-- but know that this isn't entirely portable.
GROUP BY users.id
```

Looking again at your column names, I may have misunderstood the relationship.  if `user_favorite_group.user_group_id` actually points as a `FOREIGN KEY` to `user_groups.id` rather than to `groups.id` as I've expressed it here, you actually need another additional join:

```
FROM users_groups
    INNER JOIN users ON users.id = users_groups.user_id
    INNER JOIN groups ON groups.id = users_organizations.organization_id
    -- Join user to user_favorite_group
    -- Using LEFT JOIN in case the user has no favorite, it will return a NULL.
    LEFT JOIN `user_favorite_group` ON users.id = user_favorite_group.user_id
    -- Join through `user_groups` to get the relationship
    INNER JOIN user_groups ugfav ON user_favorite_group.user_group_id = ugfav.id
    -- Join ultimlately back to `groups` to get the group name.
    INNER JOIN groups gfav ON ugfav.group_id = .gfav.id
```

Comment: If you remove the `GROUP BY`, do you get a different result?

Comment: Oh wait, is `user_favorite_group.user_group_id` a FK pointer to the `groups.id` table, or to `user_groups.id`? I may have got the wrong relation...

Comment: @chatu ialphan's comments are now gone - this comment thread has confused me tremendously. I just added a different join, because I think I had an incorrect or ambiguous relationship. Please see if this works, with the new `FROM` clause.

Comment: @chatu Glad to hear it. Which `FROM` clause was needed - the first or second?

Comment: Is there a way to select all users even if they don't belong to any group? The second select statement selects only the users that belongs to a group. Thanks!

Comment: @chatu Use a `LEFT JOIN`. You would have to change the order of joins to place `users` first, followed by `users_groups`, as in`FROM users LEFT JOIN users_groups ON users.id = users_grous.user_id... ` All subsequent joins could be in the same order

Comment: If I understood your correctly, it returns the same thing. FROM users LEFT JOIN users_organizations ON users.id = users.organizations.user_id INNER JOIN groups ON groups.id = users_organizations.organization_id... Thanks.

Comment: @chatu I suppose you also need to make the other one a `LEFT JOIN groups ON groups.id = users_organizations.organization_id` (and remove the `WHERE` clause limiting to user 1)

Comment: Sorry about the confusion in previous comment about groups and orgs. I've been trying different solutions from stackoverflow. :( Here is what I have: http://pastie.org/9820868 Thanks again for your help!

Comment: If that isn't working, setup a sample at http://sqlfiddle.com. Using _all_ left joins may be it, but I wouldn't think so.